# What is the standard way to install XBMC service and launch it automatically

Tags: service, installation, xbmc

I need to make an installation for XBMC service (not Add-on) and after installation the service must be registered to be launched automatically after XBMC start.

I can't find any description and standard solution anywhere.

It would be perfect if the XBMC service can be installed through the XBMC UI like and other Add-on.

Add-on have special structure. I am not sure if the service has the same or not.

[XBMC Wiki](http://wiki.xbmc.org/)

[XBMC](http://xbmc.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In xbmc the only services that can be setup to run when xbmc starts are python services, which are also addons.

These service addons differ from normal addons by adding the `xbmc.service` extension point and specifying a python file to execute using the following line or similar in the addon.xml file.

```xml
<extension point="xbmc.service" library="default.py" start="[login|startup]">
```

Service addons do have an identical structure to current xbmc addons.

See the xbmc wiki page [Automatically start addons using services](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=How-to:Automatically_start_addons_using_services), for further details.